# Global variable is used later and python said it's not defined

Tags: python, global-variables, selenium-chromedriver, nameerror

I'm doing some automatization with chromedriver. And i'm getting my values from our company's web based system.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
def ask_user():
global choice
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input('Milyen tesztet csinálsz? \n (1) Bejövő WR Teszt \n (2) Kimenő WR teszt \n'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Kérlek számot üss be!')
        continue
    if 0 < choice < 3:
        break
    else:
        print('Ez nem 1 és 2 között van! Próbáld újra:')

def decider():
    global path_dir
    if warr_type == warranty:
        with open('partners.json', encoding = 'utf-8') as partner_data:
            partner_db = json.load(partner_data)
    for p in partner_db.keys():
        if p == partner:
            path_dir = partner_db.get(p)           
    else:
        with open('data.json') as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
    for k in data.keys():
        if k == restring.group(1):
            path_dir = data.get(k)


def check_and_copy(): # checking for directory existence and copy based upon user choice+ decider()
    if choice == 1:
        incoming()
    else:
        outgoing()
    if not os.path.exists(path_dir):
        os.makedirs(path_dir)
        name_list = os.path.splitext(name)
        shutil.copy2('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory1.log', path_dir+name_list[0]+'-'+timestr+name_list[1])
        print ('Log átmásolva')
    else:
        # os.chdir(target_dir) felesleges sor
        name_list = os.path.splitext(name)
        shutil.copy2('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory1.log', path_dir+name_list[0]+'-'+timestr+name_list[1])
        print('Log átmásolva')
```

And the error i'm getting is:

```
  File "C:/GSM/GSM_wr_AUTO_1.7.1(exp).py", line 120, in check_and_copy
if not os.path.exists(path_dir):
NameError: name 'path_dir' is not defined
```

How is that possible that i clearly declare a global variable, and i'm getting this error?

Please help me. Also if the full code is needed let me know.

Comment: do you ever call `decider()`? you code is incomplete and you indentation is way off. people will not be able to help you that way. read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [**minimal**, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i've edited the identations which was made by the site, because i copied the source from IDLE.
And yess i'm calling said function later in my main()

Comment: You should replace your use of globals with `return` calls. Every time you use `global` a kitten dies.

Comment: The full code has be dumped to pastebin.

link:

https://pastebin.com/7vbXxD35

Comment: This kind of bug is exactly why globals are bad.  Pass parameters and return values, don't use globals unless you absolutely have no alternative.

Comment: By the way, you are asking for trouble using backslashes in a path like that, for example, what if a folder or file name started with `\n`, or `\r`, or any other special character?  Use raw strings (or forward slashes):  `r'C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory1.log'`

Comment: Ohh i didn't know such "bug" exists. As you can see i'm pretty noob when it comes to programming. I try to automate the boring stuff but my knowledge is kinda noobish :)

How can i return a said value then recall that value later in another function?

Comment: Fair enough, I was preparing an answer but was beaten to it.  I really suggest you spend a few days following a Python tutorial, there are many out there and it will save time in the long run.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Return the value at the end of `decider()`

```
def decider():
    path_dir = ""
    if warr_type == warranty:
        with open('partners.json', encoding = 'utf-8') as partner_data:
            partner_db = json.load(partner_data)
        for p in partner_db.keys():
            if p == partner:
                path_dir = partner_db.get(p)          
    else:
        with open('data.json') as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        for k in data.keys():
            if k == restring.group(1):
                path_dir = data.get(k)
   return path_dir
```

Then in `check_and_copy()` pass on that value

```
def check_and_copy(path_dir): # checking for directory existence and copy based upon user choice+ decider()
    if choice == 1:
        incoming()
    else:
        outgoing()
    if not os.path.exists(path_dir):
        os.makedirs(path_dir)
        name_list = os.path.splitext(name)
        shutil.copy2('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory1.log', path_dir+name_list[0]+'-'+timestr+name_list[1])
        print ('Log átmásolva')
    else:
        # os.chdir(target_dir) felesleges sor
        name_list = os.path.splitext(name)
        shutil.copy2('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory1.log', path_dir+name_list[0]+'-'+timestr+name_list[1])
        print('Log átmásolva')
```

In your main you can then pass it like so :

```
...
            path_dir = decider()
            ask_user()
            check_and_copy(path_dir)
...
```

Comment: See the full code here:

https://pastebin.com/7vbXxD35

you can see that in my main() it's called before check_and_copy()

Comment: What if you make `decider()` return the path_dir and then pass it on to `check_and_copy(path_dir)`?

Comment: And how exactly can i do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer which should show you how to do it.